# selecting an optimal span

Tags: javascript, algorithm, constraint-programming

This is a pure programming question. I have an array of words. The words have pauses after them with various length (mostly zero). Each word also has a certainty score. I want to select an optimal span of words from a lookahead window.

- The lower the overall certainty the better (or say the lower the 33th percentile of certainty the better).
- The longer the pauses on the edges the better (with a hard minimum).
- There would be an optimum length (like 5 seconds). The closer to it the better. There would be hard limits on mimimum and maximum length.

Nota bene, this is in JavaScript, so I cannot afford using support vector machines s or the like. :-) For performance thoughts, it will be calculated maybe every minute on a window of 2-minute length (250 words or so).

Second nota bene for those interested: This is to select a span of words generated by automatic speech recognition for manual transcription (active learning).

How would you approach this?

Comment: To start with, you need to determine a comparable way to measure the "betterness" of the different factors, so that you can calculate a value for the combination of the factors. You would need a formula for each factor that gives a value for that factor in relation to the optimal goal.

Answer (score 0):

A night's sleep brought light on the issue. There's actually very little magic needed. Since the number of candidate spans is quite limited (in the very worst case square of the number of words in the window -- 250^2), I can simply evaluate the fitness of each span and pick the one with best score.

Duh, why didn't I see this yesterday?